# How to set ImageView source to content provider throughout code?

Tags: java, android, imageview, spotify

I want to have an `ImageView` component within my activity and use `Java` to change the source.

The content provider is something like this:

```
content://com.spotify.music/image/OTIzMzlhZThkNjA2YWVkODRhZjY3NDU2YzgxNDM4MmM3NzlhMTU4MA%3D%3D%0A
```

I want to be able to change this image source whenever I want in the code.

Comment: If you have the necessary permission, ie. FileProvider permission from spotify app, you can use `ImageView.setImageUri`

Comment: @Froyo, I seem to get an issue now with permissions it seems. I get something like this now `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.spotify.music.internal.provider.SpotifyProvider from ProcessRecord{71e7ffe 28776:com.morahman.spotifywithfriends/u0a700} (pid=28776, uid=10700) that is not exported from UID 10662` Any clue?

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, you need to have a FileProvider permission from that particular app. This is a security reason that your app can not access other app's files without necessary permissions. You can use this file if the file is shared with your app by Spotify.